# Video generation with png frame with random name - Linux

Tags: linux, video, command-line

I have a folder which contains .png pictures named in the following way:

```
name_number.png
```

However the number is written in scientific way ( 1, 1e1, 1e2 ).

I would like to create a video, from command line, which is a combination of all of them.

Is there a command with Linux that takes into consideration the scientific name? Should I rename them with a command and then generate the video?

Comment: You need to give better examples than what you have here, like edit your question and show an example of all the different varieties of file-name you have. What's generating these names? What format do you *want* them in?

Comment: if when you do `ls -1` the files appear in the correct sequence, as they would in your example data, then there is nothing to do. We probably need to see more inclusive examples of your scientific numbering to help per tadman's comment. Good luck.

Comment: @tadman the name is the same for all. The only difference is the name.

Comment: @shellter 
I would like to have them sorted as 1 - 100 - 1000 in order to generate the video via command line. 
However, since the name is in scientific form they are sorted as 
1 - 1e1 - 1e2 - 2 - 2e1 - 2e2 - 3 - ...

Comment: Where are these names coming from? What tools can you use to fix it? Python? Ruby?

Comment: @tadman from a commercial FEM program. They cannot be saved with a different name, I already asked it in the dedicated forum.
I can fully use the power of an Ubuntu 17.04. 
No restrictions about installing or running programs

Comment: If you could parse this with Ruby or Python it'd be pretty trivial. If you could give some concrete examples of names plus their expected output that'd be ideal.

Comment: @tadman well instead of 
test_1.png - test_1e1.png - test_1e2.png - test_2.png I would like to have test_1.png - test_2.png - test_10.png - test_100.png

Answer (score 0):

With Ruby you can tackle it this way:

```
def rename_sci(name)
  name.sub(/(\d+e\d+)/) do |m|
    '%.0f' % $1.to_f
  end
end

%w[
  test_1e1.png
  test_1e2.png
].each do |name|
  puts '%s -> %s' % [
    name,
    rename_sci(name)
  ]
end
```

Where you get output like:

```
test_1e1.png -> test_10.png
test_1e2.png -> test_100.png
```

Now you can make an actual renaming tool pretty easily:

```
require 'optparse'

def rename_sci(name)
  name.sub(/([0-9]+e[0-9]+)/) do |m|
    '%.0f' % $1.to_f
  end
end

options = {
  dry_run: false
}

# Use OptionParser to add --dry-run option for testing
program = OptionParser.new do |op|
  op.on('-y', '--dry-run', 'Dry run, no renaming actually occurs') do
    options[:dry_run] = true
  end
end

program.parse!(ARGV).each do |path|
  new_path = rename_sci(path)

  next if (path == new_path)

  puts '%s -> %s' % [ path, new_path ]

  next if (options[:dry_run])

  File.rename(path, new_path)
end
```

Then you can run this script like:

```
rename_sci -y *.png
```

If everything looks good, pull the `-y` flag and let it rip! As always, make backups in case something goes horribly awry.